# Maintain object transform after animation

Tags: animation, transforms

I wanted to animate a revolver but I got stuck on something (to me) rather silly.

1. I have an animation that rotates the drum x-degrees (enough to rotate to the next bullet) but looping it will result in the drum always rotating from 0°-x°.
   I thought of creating separate animations for each slot (0°-x° ; x°-2x° and so on), but the amount of animations seems pointless considering they're technically all doing the same thing.
2. When reloading, the drum has to flip out of the side and stay in place until the drum is filled, but the amount of bullets that have to be reloaded is variable (between 1 and as many bullets as the drum can hold) so I can't say "it has to stay open x-frames" thus I want the drum to maintain the transform it has at the end of my 'flip open drum' animation.
   Alternatively I could, once again, create separate animations for each possible value, but it feels like a lot of unnecessary work.

So I'm left with the question: Can I maintain the transform of an object at the end (or any other point in time) of an animation?

Or in other words: Are there animations that add to the current transform of an object instead of overriding it?

Comment: I don't have time right now to give details, but the way I would do it would be through parenting to empty's and drivers.

Comment: The NLA editor allows you to blend and sequence animations. So you might have an action of the cylinder rotating 60 degrees. You can sequence that animation repeatedly on different tracks, and have them blend additively so that the rotations accumulate. Likewise, an action of the cylinder flipping out for reloading can be sequenced independently of the rotations of the cylinder.